# FinancialData function error

Tags: curated-data

FinancialData["EEM"] - I am using this function get some data and getting this error. Can anyone help with the same

Internet download of data for FinancialData  failed. Use Help > 
Internet Connectivity... to test or reconfigure internet connectivity.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Works fine for me. Did you try "Test Internet Connectivity" under Help > Internet Connectivity?

Comment: Works in Mma 13.0.1 on Win 10.

Comment: Also works fine in MMA 13.0 on MacOS 11.5.2

Comment: Similar question posted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2518997).

Comment: I did the test intenet connectivity and it gives the message 'connectivity test succedeed

Comment: I have the same problem: same error message but when I test the internet connectivity as instructed, Wolfram reports back that the test was successful (and the internet is indeed working and, e.g., weather data is downloading just fine. I suspect a temporary glitch with the Wolfram servers for financial data?